# DRF 3.0 Returning serialized data with None values.

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have the follow model.

```
class Sale(models.Model):
    # a sale can be made by a directSale or an Access
    directSale = models.ForeignKey('selling.DirectSale', null=True, blank=True)

    access = models.ForeignKey('access.Access', null=True, blank=True)

    product = models.ForeignKey(CustomProduct)

    price_table = models.ForeignKey('products.CustomPriceTable',   related_name='sales', null=True)

    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        'quantidade', null=False, blank=False, default=0,
    )

    discount = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        'desconto', null=False, blank=False, default=0,
    )

    original_price = models.DecimalField(
    'preço original', null=False, blank=False, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0,
    )

    discount_price = models.DecimalField(
    'preço com desconto', null=False, blank=False, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0,
    )

    total = models.DecimalField(
    'Valor total', null=False, blank=False, default=0, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2
    )

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(
        'Criada em', auto_now_add=True
    )
```

To serializer the model above, i have the follow Serializer

```
class SaleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product_pv = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='product.pv')
    product_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='product.name')
    product_id = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='product.id')
    direct_sale_date = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='directSale.date')
    client = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='directSale.client.name')

    def __init__(self, direct_sale, *args, **kwargs):
        self.direct_sale = direct_sale
        super(SaleSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        sale = Sale(**validated_data)
        sale.directSale = self.direct_sale
        price_table = sale.directSale.account.preferences_dict['table_sale']
        sale.price_table = sale.product.price_tables.get(name=price_table)
        sale.total = sale.calculate_value()
        sale.save()
        return sale

    class Meta:
        model = Sale
        fields = (
            'id',
            'access',
            'directSale',
            'discount',
            'discount_price',
            'original_price',
            'price_table',
            'product',
            'quantity',
            'total',
            'direct_sale_date',
            'product_pv',
            'product_name',
            'product_id',
            'client',
            'created_at'
        )
```

Why the below code is returning None in the values of fields?

```
from selling.api.serializers import SaleSerializer
from selling.models import Sale

sale = Sale.objects.all()[0]
sale.quantity
1
serializer = SaleSerializer(sale)

serializer.data
ReturnDict([('access', None), ('directSale', None), ('discount', None), ('discount_price', None), ('original_price', None), ('price_table', None), ('product', None), ('quantity', None), ('total', None)])
```

As you can see above, the value of quantity attribute is equal to 1. But in the 'serializer.data' the value of quantity attribute is None.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your `SaleSerializer` your first argument is `direct_sale` and you pass your instance as the parameter for `direct_sale`.

You should be calling it like

```
serializer = SaleSerializer(True, sale)
```

or

```
serializer = SaleSerializer(True, instance=sale)
```